# Autocompletion in joe or jed editor

Tags: c, autocomplete, editor

I want to use joe or jed to code in C language. Any way to have autocompletion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. In the last hours I have learned the following (Only for **jed**):

Checking at [Guido Gonzato's excellent Quick Reference Guide.](https://sites.google.com/site/guidogonzato/jed/jed-quickref.html?attredirects=0)  we found:

> Completion is the automatic expansion of partially-typed words. If
>   your text contains the word `frobnication', typing`fro' followed by
>   M-/ (M-X dabbrev) will either expand the whole word, or cycle amongst
>   all possible completions.

It works for previously typed keywords.

A better autocompletion can be obtained through [complete mode](http://jedmodes.sourceforge.net/mode/complete/). you will need: 
[Installing modes from Jedmodes](http://jedmodes.sourceforge.net/doc/install.html).

Answer (score 2):

`joe` and `jed` are two completely different programs, but the answer is "not really" for both:

- `jed`: theoretically yes, but practically no. The home page claims that jed is "extensible in the C-like S-Lang language making the editor completely customizable". You might be able to hack in autocompletion this way, but it'd probably be more work than learning to use a better text editor.
- `joe`'s documentation claims that you can "complete word in edit buffer by hitting ESC Enter (uses other words in buffer for dictionary)". Which is something, but it's not full autocompletion.

Comment: I have not asking for the best text editor, but thanks for your opinion. Yes, I've also visited both homepages. Do you have used both editors? Thanks anyway.